# How to force a TextChanged event on a WPF TextBox and mantain the focus?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I am creating a numeric TextBox in **WPF**, with two buttons to increase and decrease the value.

I have create two **RoutedCommand** to manage the behiavor and they are working well. There is only one problem that I would like to solve. I would like that the control notifies all object binded to its **TextProperty** when an increase or decrease command is executed.

At the moment it sends the notification **only when I change the focus to another control**

Any help is really appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"` in the Binding and in `TextChanged` event update the `BindingSource`.
so you are writing something like this:

```
<NumericTextBox x:Name="control" Text={Binding Path=MyProperty}/>
```

instead do like this

```
<NumericTextBox x:Name="control" Text={Binding Path=MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}/>
```

and in `TextChanged` event handler update the binding.

```
control.GetBindingExpression(NumericTextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

and thats done.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: @viky thanks a lot! I forgot that was possible use the expression "control.GetBindingExpression(NumericTextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();" that is perfect. I am calling it only when the user press increase and decrease buttons and use the normal behavior when change text manually.

Comment: Why not simply use `Text="{Binding YourBindableProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`?

Answer (score 33):

There is a simple way:

```
Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

(I tested it on TextBox).
Good Luck

Comment: +1. `Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` seems to be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for the binding of the Text property on a `TextBox` is to update on `LostFocus`.  You can change this in your custom control by overriding the metadata on the `TextProperty` in your static ctor:

```
static NumericTextBox()
{
    TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(NumericTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", // default value
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            null,  // property change callback
            null,  // coercion callback
            true,  // prohibits animation
            UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));
}
```

Comment: @abe thank you Abe, very useful but viky answer is more flexible for my case